# ¿Cómo agregar una cabecera de transporte en el servidor Weblogic (CORS)?

Tags: asp.net, webservice, iis, soap, weblogic

Trabajo con Oracle SOA Suite y necesito una cabecera de transporte "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" en la configuración del servidor weblogic para obtener esto: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta imagen es de un servicio en IIS7, que tiene configurado lo siguiente:

`<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS,POST" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,SOAPAction,origin" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>`

¿Cómo hago esto en el servidor weblogic?

En el browser con weblogic, por defecto se muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: _Si no me equivoco_ debes tener acceso al servidor para modificar el archivo de configuración para que el servidor permita peticiones de diferentes dominios; revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/4092887) para obtener mas información.

Comment: Tengo acceso al archivo de configuración, pero no se que línea de código debo colocar para recibir peticiones de diferentes dominios @Mauricio

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la siguiente [fuente](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html), para habilitar peticiones de otros dominios debes agregar las siguientes líneas en tu archivo `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

NOTA: Te recomiendo investigar como permitir las peticiones de ciertos dominios; ya que si compartes información sensible, no creo que permitir peticiones de otros dominios sea la mejor opción.

Consulta las siguientes preguntas y respuestas que adjunto a continuación:

- **[“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/4092887)**
- **[WCF AND CORS: “NO ‘ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN’ HEADER IS PRESENT ON THE REQUESTED RESOURCE”](https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/wcf-and-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/)**

Comment: Esas líneas de código, son para un servidor en asp.net. Justo los servicios que tengo en IIS, los tengo configurados así como expresas, pero no se como hacer lo mismo con los servicios desplegados en weblogic.

Comment: @maryvargas, por favor actualiza tu pregunta con la información que puedas agregar sobre los servicios que has desplegado. No te comprendo si te refieres a servicios web `.asmx` o `svc`.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que tengo unos servicios web en IIS en ellos tengo configurado CORS, mediante el código que muestro, muy parecido al código que tu colocaste, por ende en la cabecera de respuesta obtengo lo que se muestra en la primera imagen. Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo hago eso en weblogic? ya que tengo servicios desplegado en ese servidor.

Comment: @maryvargas debes aplicar estas lineas **en el servidor de weblogic**.