# XMLHttpRequest cannot load al cargar un json por GET

Tags: angularjs

Este es mi codigo.

```js
var app = angular.module('adminPanel', []);

app.controller('namesController', function($scope, $http) {
     var root = 'http://samp.newclan.com.uy:3000/api';

$http.get(root + "/users")
    .then(function (response) {
    $scope.names = response.data;
    });
});
```

Y este es el error que devuelve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede deberse a que el sitio _en tu caso_ `samp.newclan` no permite peticiones de otros dominios. Para mas información, consulta esta [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39144/78).

Comment: Estas seguro que la pagina existe y permite traer ese json??

Comment: Solucionado, era que no tenia habilitado CROS en mi rest api con NodeJS